# Space-specific Contexts

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've created a space using a custom type. Pretty simple, it just overrides the Drupal variables "site_frontpage" and "theme_default" when someone is inside of the space (using a PURL prefix). Lovely!

Now, when inside of this space, I'd like to disable certain Contexts, and enable other Contexts. For example, when in the space, display blockB instead of blockA, and set the breadcrumb to something different. Can this be done with Spaces out-of-the-box? If not, what could I do from my module to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Context allows you to display Block B instead of Block A depending on the URL, since Contexts allow for URL-sensitive Conditions:

The context admin screen is in admin/build/context.

[image]